# FFMPEG libx264 on Ubuntu 16

Tags: video, ffmpeg, compression

I have FFMPEG installed on my Ubuntu 16 but I want to use libx264 codec which I am unable to use. My current FFMPEG version is

```
ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version N-90418-g74c6a6d Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 20160609
configuration: --prefix= --enable-pic --disable-yasm --enable-shared
libavutil      56. 11.100 / 56. 11.100
libavcodec     58. 15.100 / 58. 15.100
libavformat    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
libavdevice    58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
libavfilter     7. 13.100 /  7. 13.100
libswscale      5.  0.102 /  5.  0.102
libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ffmpeg` was not compiled properly. You have 3 options:

- Use `ffmpeg` from the repository: `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`
- Or [download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) an already compiled `ffmpeg` and put it in `/usr/local/bin` or `~/bin`.
- Or [compile `ffmpeg`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) with `--enable-libx264 --enable-gpl` and **without** `--disable-yasm`.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. I have tried the 3rd option. I had disabled yasm when installed the first time. I did described changes but when I do make install I have this error: INSTALL libavdevice/libavdevice.a install: cannot remove '/usr/local/lib/libavdevice.a': Permission denied ffbuild/library.mak:102: recipe for target 'install-libavdevice-static' failed make: *** [install-libavdevice-static] Error 1

Comment: @Kanza You probably need to use `sudo make install`.

Comment: After running sudo make install

ffmpeg -i example.mov -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -preset fast -profile:v main -acodec aac example.mp4 -hide_banner

Comment: Please guide me how to use already compiled ffmpeg?

Which file I should download from here: https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Comment: @Kanza What exactly do you need help with? Download it, and move the `ffmpeg` executable you just downloaded into `/usr/local/bin`. Now when you run the `ffmpeg` command it should use the version you downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

On modern versions of Ubuntu, you can also install `ffmpeg` using `snap`:

```
sudo apt install snapd
# snap search ffmpeg  # Version 4.1.4 is currently available
# snap info ffmpeg
snap install ffmpeg
```

Ouptut of `ffmpeg -version`:

```
ffmpeg version n4.1.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)
configuration: --prefix= --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-doc --disable-static --enable-avisynth --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-libdrm --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-sdl2 --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxvid --enable-nonfree --enable-nvenc --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-shared --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-xlib
libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
```

As you can see in the list of configuration arguments, it has been configured with `--enable-libx264` as desired!